# Caddy TLS doesn't work in Kafka Connect UI

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, caddy

I used this documentaion to configure TLS/SSL in Kafka Connect UI:

https://hub.docker.com/r/landoop/kafka-connect-ui/

But there doesn't write anything about TLS/SSL. After that I found Caddy documentation and this page:

https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/tls

It says that to configure SSL u should to write this:

`tls cert.pem key.pem`

I tried to write this in my docker-compose.yml:

`CADDY_OPTIONS: tls cert.pem key.pem`

But SSL is still not configured.
Please help to solve the problem